# Android color notification icon in status bar

Tags: android, notifications

I would like to make the notification icon that appears in the status bar color as seen in the screenshot below. I have heard its impossible on more recent versions of android but I have also read its possible but just discouraged. If its not possible how do TikTok and some other apps do it?

I do not even need multi-color just single color would work for my requirements. I do have color in my icon resource but its converted to a solid color based on android theme kinda like the camera icon in the screenshot below.

[image]